# How to access files within the wwwroot folder of a different project?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have 2 projects that are needing to talk to one another.  The first is a ASP.NET MVC project, that when in production, has a feature where the user can edit an html template that is stored in the wwwroot folder of the project.

The second project is a C# console app that grabs some user data from a database, and then uses that data to email surveys to users.  The html template from the first project is needing to be grabbed by this console app so that it can be used in sending out these emails.  I was hoping to use HtmlAgilityPack to grab the html email template from the first project when it is live, something along the lines of this:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load("www.sitename.com/EmailTemplate");
string text = document.ParsedText;
```

But I'm open to other ideas that might work in this case. More or less I think I just need to figure out how to access static html files from within the wwwroot folder from a browser path, if that's possible. Oh and these two projects are going to be running on different servers, so local paths won't work.  Thank you!

Comment: why does this survey email program need to be a console app? Why not part of the same MVC project? Or a windows service on the server where it can read the HTML file quite happily without resorting to web scraping workarounds? If it really must run on separate servers, just set up a UNC fileshare which exposes the HTML file and permission to read it is only granted to the other application's service account. Or just make a HTTP request to the file, since it's apparently hosted within your IIS directory. No need for HTML Agility pack for that, a standard HTTP request would do. Lots of ways!

Comment: And another option is not to have a physical HTML file at all, but just store the HTML as a string in the database, where everyone can access it quite happily.

Comment: Yeah this whole thing is an unfortunate setup, but it's how the client is wanting it done, as they have one server that runs all of their scheduled windows services, and another that hosts all of their internal and external sites, and they didn't want any comingling.  Also, their database structure isn't something I have access to modify, so I couldn't add a string to store the HTML in. You're right though, an HTTP request would make more sense, I was just having difficulty figuring out the correct URL to use for getting the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In large part thanks to ADyson's comments, the course of action that makes most sense in this situation is to create a small API within the MVC app, that fetches the html file, and the console app will call this API to retrieve the needed html.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I did it by adding ~/ in the beginning of my static file addresses in my _Layout.cshtml.
My template files and photos were no longer loaded in the project but the layout was loaded. This way the files were also loaded